# JavaScript for of with list of object refactoring

Tags: javascript

I have a below Javascript code

```
const list = [
 {header: "header1", code: ""},
 {header: "header2", code: ""},
 {label: "label1", price: 10},
 {header: "header3", price: 10}
], maxHeader = 2
let result = [], headCounter = 0;

for (const [index, val] of list.entries()) {
  if (val.header) {
    headCounter++
  }
  if (headCounter <= maxHeader) 
      result.push(val)
  else break;
}
console.log(result)
```

And below is the corresponding output from the above code

```
[
  {
        header: "header1",
        code: ""
    },
    {
        header: "header2",
        code: ""
    },
    {
        label: "label1",
        price: 10
    }
]
```

is there any way to refactor the above javascript code without using for of?

Comment: What's the problem you're having with `for..of`? Why don't you want to use it, or what do you want to use instead?

Comment: I'm getting lint issues of not reusing of index

Comment: If you don't use the index, why not just `for(val of list)`?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the use of `for..of` loop that produce the same `result` can be achieved using the `reduce()` method as detailed below:

```js
const list = [
 {header: "header1", code: ""},
 {header: "header2", code: ""},
 {label: "label1", price: 10},
 {header: "header3", price: 10}
];

const maxHeader = 2;

/* Use destructuring to extract the result array from reduction 
once complete */ 
const { result } = list.reduce(({ headerCount, result }, item) => {

  /* Same logic as in your for..loop */
  if(item.header) {
    headerCount++;
  }
  
  /* Same logic as in your for..loop */
  if(headerCount <= maxHeader) {
    result.push(item);
  }
  
  /* Return state for reduction from this iteration, carrying through
  the headerCount and result array */
  return {
    headerCount,
    result
  }
  
}, { headerCount : 0, result : [] }); /* Inital state for reduction */

console.log(result);
```

#### Update

This updated method should resolve the "Assignment to function parameter"  linting error that you're getting:

```
const { result } = list.reduce(({ headerCount, result }, item) => {

  /* Increment header count on new local variable rather than
  reuse/assign to variable passed from function parameter */
  const headerCountNew = headerCount + (item.header ? 1 : 0);

  if(headerCountNew <= maxHeader) {
    result.push(item);
  }

  return {
    headerCount : headerCountNew,
    result
  }

}, { headerCount : 0, result : [] }); /* Inital state for reduction */
```

Comment: I want the output as I mentioned in the question, but I don't see the same response with your code.

Comment: I want the output as I mentioned in the question, but I don't see the same response with your code.

Comment: @Digital sorry noticed an error I had made. Just updated answer. Does that help?

Comment: Pretty nice way to use destructuring in reduce

Comment: @Dacre works nice, but I see a lint error: Assignment to function parameter 'headerCount'

Comment: @Digital just updated answer - does that resolve your linting error?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that you're not using `index`, a simple fix would be to just omit it from the destructuring:

```js
const list = [
  {header: "header1", code: ""},
  {header: "header2", code: ""},
  {label: "label1", price: 10},
  {header: "header3", price: 10}
];
const maxHeader = 2
let result = [], headCounter = 0;

for (const [, val] of list.entries()) {
  if (val.header) {
    headCounter++
  }
  if (headCounter <= maxHeader) 
      result.push(val)
  else break;
}
console.log(result)
```

You could also iterate over the array itself, rather than the `entries`:

```js
const list = [
  {header: "header1", code: ""},
  {header: "header2", code: ""},
  {label: "label1", price: 10},
  {header: "header3", price: 10}
];
const maxHeader = 2
let result = [], headCounter = 0;

for (const val of list) {
  if (val.header) {
    headCounter++
  }
  if (headCounter <= maxHeader) 
      result.push(val)
  else break;
}
console.log(result)
```

To avoid `for..of` completely, while also being able to break use a plain `for` loop:

```js
const list = [
  {header: "header1", code: ""},
  {header: "header2", code: ""},
  {label: "label1", price: 10},
  {header: "header3", price: 10}
];
const maxHeader = 2
let result = [], headCounter = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  const val = list[i];
  if (val.header) {
    headCounter++
  }
  if (headCounter <= maxHeader) 
      result.push(val)
  else break;
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I see below lint error: iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following answer using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const list = [
  { header: "header1", code: "" },
  { header: "header2", code: "" },
  { label: "label1", price: 10 },
  { header: "header3", price: 10 }
];
const maxHeader = 2;
let headCounter = 0;

const output = list.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  if (currentValue.hasOwnProperty('header')) {
      headCounter++;
  }

  if (headCounter <= maxHeader) {
      accumulator = accumulator.concat(currentValue)
  }

  return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 4));
```